# Out of Stack Space Error (Stack Overflow Error)

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, webresource.axd

In my website I am opening a New Window by clicking on a Image Linkbutton in the page before that the other Link buttons are working fine but After closing the newly opened window When I try to click the Link Buttons it throws the **Out of Stack Space** error in Webresource.axd file in

```
function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit() {
if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
    theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value = window.pageYOffset;
    theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value = window.pageXOffset;
}
else {
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value = WebForm_GetScrollX();
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value = WebForm_GetScrollY();
}
if ((typeof(this.oldSubmit) != "undefined") && (this.oldSubmit != null)) {
    return this.oldSubmit(); // Error thrown here
}
return true;
```

}

Kindly any one point me what could be the Problem.

This is the Screen shot of the Webresource.axd

**Edit:**
In the `this.oldsubmitcode` I am only getting the following methods

```
callBaseMethod() = callBaseMethod(a, d, b)
getBaseMethod() = getBaseMethod(a, b)
getBaseType() = getBaseType()
getInterfaces() = getInterfaces()
getName() = getName()
implementsInterface() = implementsInterface(d)
inheritsFrom() = inheritsFrom(b)
initializeBase() = initializeBase(a, b)
isImplementedBy() = isImplementedBy(a)
isInstanceOfType() = isInstanceOfType(a)
registerClass() = registerClass(c, b, d)
registerEnum() = registerEnum(b, c)
registerInterface() = registerInterface(a)
resolveInheritance() = resolveInheritance()
```

I had Found in this link [Modal dialog boxes Stack Overflow Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895194) that Opening More than one Modal dialog Box in Internet Explorer may cause Stack Overflow Error

Comment: can we see the `oldSubmit()` code?

Comment: Looks like an endless recursion to me...

Comment: @Mario Stoilov I have edited it with screen shot

Comment: This is the backend to some page, right? Can you post the frontend? Some binding might be causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this.oldSubmit is (directly or indirectly) recursively calling WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit. Check the value of this.oldSubmit, and make sure the function it references is not recursively calling WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit.